# I deploy python SimpleHTTPServer and put html file into it. But after a couple of requests to it, the server stops responding

Tags: linux, http

I use this command:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 9023 >/dev/null 2>/dev/null &.
```

The port is not busy and listening, the firewall is disabled
Аfter which I check the server in the browser: http://localhost:9023

So far so good, but after a couple of attempts the server stops responding.
And this I can see in `strace` [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsBSt.png)

Comment: Maybe don't redirect the server output to `/dev/null` in case it prints something helpful? Or redirect to a file?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.